# How to convert string to Python object (Flask specific)

Tags: python, flask

If I have this code:

```
from datetime import timezone
DEFAULT_TZ = timezone.utc
```

And I want to pass `timezone.utc` as an input variable from a JSON file:

```
from datetime import timezone

app.config.from_file(filename="config.json", load=json.load)
DEFAULT_TZ = app.config['DEFAULT_TIMEZONE']
```

Where `config.json` is:

```
{
  "DEFAULT_TIMEZONE": "timezone.utc"
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: I implemented some ideas below, I hope it works what u want

Answer (score 0):

Timezone.utc is an object. One function returns that object according to the string from the dictionary (config file).

**IDEA1:**
Brainstorming idea:

```
from datetime import timezone
from flask import Flask

app.config.from_json("config.json")

def get_timezone(timezone_str):
    if timezone_str == "utc":
        return timezone.utc
    return None
 
DEFAULT_TZ = get_timezone(app.config['DEFAULT_TIMEZONE'])
```

config.json:

```
{
  "DEFAULT_TIMEZONE": "utc"
}
```

**IDEA2:**

If you want to use different zones, and string as parameter, this may help you.

Sample Code:

```
import datetime
import pytz

current_time_utc = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.UTC)

eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
current_time_eastern = datetime.datetime.now(eastern)

london = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
current_time_london = datetime.datetime.now(london)

print("Current time in UTC:", current_time_utc)
print("Current time in US/Eastern:", current_time_eastern)
print("Current time in Europe/London:", current_time_london)
```

Sample config.json:

```
{
  "DEFAULT_TIMEZONE": "US/Eastern"
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
import datetime
import pytz
from flask import Flask

app.config.from_json("config.json")
DEFAULT_TZ = pytz.timezone(app.config['DEFAULT_TIMEZONE'])
```

All timezones' strings:

```
print(pytz.all_timezones)
```